# Trying to execute wget command from azurerm_virtual_machine_extension through terraform, however curl unable to execute

Tags: azure, shell, command-line, wget, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to execute wgetcommand from azurerm_virtual_machine_extension through terraform, however, curl unable to execute. here is the code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "extension_v1" {
  name                       = "vm-extension"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_virtual_machine.PrimaryVM.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                       = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version       = "2.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    { 
     "commandToExecute": " sudo wget -P /etc "https://example.sh";"    
    }
    SETTINGS
}
```

requirement is to download a file using wget.
Unable to execute curl command for Azure extension

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to execute the wget command from azurerm_virtual_machine_extension through Terraform, and I was able to check with a fix that needs to be placed in the configuration.

The code snippet seems to have a problem with the way the string is formatted inside the JSON block. You have double quotes inside double quotes without escaping them, which will cause a JSON parsing error.

If you're trying to use `wget`, stick to that and don't mix with `curl`. Both `wget` and `curl` are tools to fetch content from the web, but they have different syntax and options.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Demorg-vk"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "sbvk-network"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "sbvk-publicip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "sbvk-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "sbvk-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "osdisk-example"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "admin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "sbvk-vm-extension"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "sudo wget -P /etc 'https://example.sh'"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

Once you're done with configuring the domain mentioned with shell script. i.e., example.sh

Start executing the commands

**Terraform init**

**Terraform plan**

**Terraform apply**

By making the necessary changes in the code mentioned we shall be able to execute the wget command from azurerm_virtual_machine_extension through terraform.

Once you're able to run the command run the URL to download the shell script you are trying to do so.